# Cant figure out how to get bootstrap table to work with electron renderer

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-4, electron

I am trying to integrate bootstrap data table with an electron app. I got the table itself up and running on the HTML side but I can't seem to figure out the way to get the renderer (js) to communicate with the DataTable element.

I've tried accessing the functions directly with:

```js
var toolTable = document.getElementById('toolTable');
toolTable.bootstrapTable({});
```

but that just result with:

> Uncaught TypeError: toolTable.bootstrapTable is not a function

any pointer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what 'bootstrapTable' function is supposed to be doing?  But if it is supposed to be a function added by some external library on top of jQuery - first make sure you import jQuery **before** the library that may utilize it.

If this is not the case, you can populate a table dynamically by using jquery .innerHTML() to your table.  Or, you can use DataTables as per: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap